# Spark-Koalas Error: Column assignment doesn't support type tuple

Tags: spark-koalas

I am unable to assign `kdf[c].factorize()` to `kdf[c]`.

I tried this but it didn't help:

```
ks.set_option('compute.ops_on_diff_frames', True)
kdf[response] = ks.Series(kdf[response].factorize())
ks.reset_option('compute.ops_on_diff_frames')
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`factorize` returns a tuple `(Series, Index)`. You can assign the first element of the tuple to the response column. It is already a Series, so no need to convert it using `ks.Series`. Try this code:

```
kdf[response] = kdf[response].factorize()[0]
```

PS No need for setting `ops_on_diff_frames` because you're only working on a single dataframe here.